# IOS Swift error reading Json String value

Tags: json, swift, swift3

I am getting data from a URL and it is coming back in Json . What I am trying to do is color a certain button Blue if a particular Json column does not contain null or Nil . This is My Json

**{"votes":"0","vote_status":null},{"votes":"1","vote_status":"11"}**

as you can see the field vote_status returns as a String however if the value is null then it doesn't have any quotation marks around it . How can I check for Null values in my code

```
// This will store all the vote_status values
    var VoteStatus =  [String]()

  // captures the value 
        if var vote_Status = Stream["vote_status"] as? String {

                            self.VoteStatus.append(vote_Status)
                        }
```

However I get an error **fatal error: Index out of range**

Which I am positive it is because the NuLL values does not have any strings . Is there a way I can check for NULL values and change them to something like "null" ? I have tried doing it this way

```
  if var voteStatus = Stream["vote_status"] as? String {
                                if vote_Status == nil {
                                   vote_Status = "null"
                                }
                                self.VoteStatus.append(vote_Status)
                            }
```

and it states that comparing non-optional value of type String to nil is always false . The code above compiles but gives an error on Runtime . I am new to Swift but any suggestions would be great..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting that compiletime error is that if this passes: `if var voteStatus = Stream["vote_status"] as? String {` then that is a guarantee that `Stream["vote_status"]` is a non-nil String value.  If you want to do something different if that IS a nil, then just put an `else` statement:

```
if var voteStatus = Stream["vote_status"] as? String {
    //Do whatever you want with a guaranteed, non-nil String
} else {
    //It's nil
}
```

If you also want to treat the string `"null"` as a nil value, you can add one little bit:

```
if var voteStatus = Stream["vote_status"] as? String, voteStatus != "null" {
    //Do whatever you want with a guaranteed, non-nil, non-"null" String
} else {
    //It's nil or "null"
}
```

The `index out of range` error is likely caused by something that we're not seeing in your code.  Is `Stream` itself an optional? In your second example are you forgetting to initialize your `voteStatus` array?

Comment: Thanks a lot that is exactly what was needed